# PHP, MySQL Undefined Index

Tags: php, mysql

```
 9 <?php include 'db.php';
10 $vin = $_GET['VIN'];
11 $query = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE VIN='$vin'";
```

I understand this is a beginner issue, but I'm having trouble understanding why I'm receiving this error:

**(!) Notice: Undefined index: VIN in C:\wamp\www\php\viewcar.php on line 10**

I have a VIN column in the MySQL database and I'm not sure why it's not displaying. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Answer (score 0):

in PHP `$_GET` is an associative array, so in the case of `$_GET['VIN']` the index is `'VIN'`. `$_GET` is filled with parameters passed in the url, while it is possible to change how your http server handles get parameters the most common is like this `http://yoursite.com/mypage.php?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2` 
in your case since since your are receiving the error on line 10 it means there is no item in your `$_GET` array with the index of `'VIN'`. The easiest way to prevent this error would be something like this

```
<?php include 'db.php';
    if(isset($_GET['VIN'])){
        $vin=$_GET['VIN'];
        $query="SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE VIN=:vin";
        $stmt=$pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':vin',$vin);
        $products = array();
        if ($stmt->execute()){
            //handle results
        }
    }else{
        //handle VIN not being set
    }
```

Please also note that you should not concatenate your query, ever so in my example I showed using PDO and a prepared statement. you can learn more about using PDO here http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to work you have to enter a VIN number after the url. The VIN number that is located in your database. Without the VIN number nothing works.

```
viewcar.php?VIN=1B3EL46J25N513802
```

This returns the following

```
2005 Dodge Stratus 
Asking Price: 7995.00 
Exterior Color: Blue
Interior Color: Gray
```